# When one function ends the other one also ends in multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I'm using a multiprocessing library, running two functions at the same time. I want to at some point finish one of the two functions and when that function finishes the other function should also end.

Example:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process

def a():
    while True:
        print('a')
        break
        
def b():
    while True:
        print('b')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pA = Process(target=a)
    pB = Process(target=b)
```

In the code above, how would I do it so that when the function a is stopped, consequently it also stop the function b (which is repeating itself)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your text does not contain a question. It might be a problem about not being a native speaker, but your sentences do not make it clear what your goal is.

Comment: ok, I will edit

Comment: Not perfect, but now the question is clear :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `multiprocessing.Event` to communicate to `b()` that `a()` ended.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Event

def a(stopEvent):
    while True:
        print('a')
        break
    stopEvent.set()
        
def b(stopEvent):
    while True:
        print('b')
        if stopEvent.is_set():
            break;

if __name__ == '__main__':
    stopEvent = Event()
    pA = Process(target=a, args=(stopEvent,))
    pB = Process(target=b, args=(stopEvent,))
    pB.start()
    pA.start()
    pA.join()
    pB.join()
```

Comment: Upvote, but, yes, technically this is still plagiarism, but since we have communicated I'm going to let it go ;-)

Comment: Well, it's not, technically I'm closer to @TheHatter's code then to yours :P

Comment: I'm try using a if statement

Comment: You might need to provide more information than that, if that's a question. If it's a statement, then I'm unsure what you are trying to say :)

Comment: Edited my code as a wild guess of what you are trying to say.

Comment: Yep. I will try now

Comment: No problem :)
But I don't think it's actually your english. If you have a question, actually write it as a question, otherwise it's confusing :) A sentence with a dot at the end is a statement, not a question.

Comment: I finally solved my problem, you guys helped me a lot, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Queue` from one `Process` to the other:

```py
#soMultiprocessingOneProcessEndsAnother
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time

def a(q):
    while True:
        print('a')
        break
    q.put(None)
    print('a Done')
        
def b(q):
    while q.empty():
        print('b')
        time.sleep(0.01)
    print('b Done')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pq = Queue()
    pA = Process(target=a, args=(pq,))
    pB = Process(target=b, args=(pq,))
    pB.start()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    pA.start()
    pA.join()
    pB.join()
    print('m Done')
```

Sample Output:

```
b
b
b
b
b
b
b
a
a Done
b Done
m Done
```

Comment: I like the general concept, but i'd use `multiprocessing.Event` instead

Comment: That sounds like it is worth an answer.

Comment: What exactly is join() for?

Comment: Waits until the process is finished

Comment: Sure, I can create a separate answer, I just didn't want to steal yours, as it's 90% identical :)

Comment: I'm actually working with a only function, but i execute it (asynchronously) many times with a for loop. So i 'm trying addapt this for only a def